# The resource cannot be found error in web API MVC 4

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api, restful-architecture

My web api looks working and it  dispalys data in json format

```
http://localhost:60783/api/employee/GetEmployeeList/
```

but when i try to point out the .cshtm file then it gives me :

```
 The resource cannot be found error .
```

my routeConfig looks like this

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
```

And my webApiConfig :

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
```

my Global.asax :

```
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);           
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
```

I have controller called  `EmployeeController`
i amcalling the api using

```
 public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {


        HttpResponseMessage response = await ServiceAccess.Get("Employee/GetEmployeeList", null);
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            List<Employee> model = await ServiceAccess.DeserializeAs<List<Employee>>(response);

            return View(model);
        }
        return Content("No Record");
    }

    public ActionResult EmployeeList()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

service Access class :

```
public static HttpClient httpClient;

    static ServiceAccess()
    {
        httpClient = new HttpClient();
        httpClient.BaseAddress = GeneralConstants.ServiceBaseURI;
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

    }

    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static async Task<T> DeserializeAs<T>(HttpResponseMessage SerializedResponse)
    {
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(await SerializedResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().ConfigureAwait(false));
    }

    //mis named the name should be GetMany
    [MethodImpl(MethodImplOptions.AggressiveInlining)]
    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> GetAll(string uri)
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return response;
    }
```

and web config file has this

```
<add key="ServiceBaseURI" value="http://localhost:60783/api/" />
```

the lnk which gives me problem :

```
http://localhost:60783/Employee/EmployeeList/
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: how you are calling this api?

Comment: i added , please take a look again.

Comment: You question is really confusing; half of your code is not even related to your question. If API works and returns JSON, it might be something to do with **ServiceAccess** class.

Comment: your question isn't clear. can you show the code for `ServiceAccess`?

Comment: added part of service access class

Comment: check the controller name folder location. If everything is correct it should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few bug in your code. If you consider and debug your code you will get the answer.

- Your API controller name `EmployeeController` and MVC controller name `EmployeeController` is same.
- Your need to provide correct URL of the Employee API in your case it might be inside some folder because In one controller folder you can not create two controller with same name(in your case it seems like your MVC and Web API controller name is same.
- Pock the web API method using DHC or Postmen and check what response you are getting and use the same URL in you MVC controller.